# Graphs for complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

The cartesian graphing system is based on using three mutually perpendicular lines to plot a point in $3D$ space.
But that is for real numbers and no graphs for complex numbers exist.
For eg. If I Have a function $y=x^2-i,$where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ And i want to find its root graphically then how can i plot a graph which will help me?
$\because$ real numbers require only one number to specify them while complex numbers need two it won't be very easy, Please help...

Comment: @HansLundmark that's different i want to find roots using graphs

Comment: Yes, you look at the picture and then you see where the roots are. If you color by argument, you can even see the multiplicity of the zeros in the picture. See the link in the first comment to that question (by Chris Brooks).

Comment: See also [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7FxPsqfkOY)